# Is possible to filter blank fields on multi_select?

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I want to know if its possible to get the rows with empty fields on this columns. I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/m26jzxsf/) to explain this.

At first column (Status) I have three values (ON, OFF, (EMPTY)). My problem is to get the rows with empty values (Same row as PR00000003, PR00000005) selecting empty value on the filter.

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: do you want (EMPTY) means (clear row value ) to be filtered

Comment: I want to select in the filter (EMPTY) (or something else) and the table show me only this two rows.

Comment: with yadcf it is not working, but without yadcf it is possible

Comment: lets see if someone could help me with YADCF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there seems to be some sort of issue with yadcf/select2 and empty string for filtering I can suggest the following solutions:

1) Use regex ([see this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m26jzxsf/10/)) -

```
    var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

    yadcf.init(oTable, [
        {
            column_number: 0,
            filter_type: 'multi_select',
            append_data_to_table_data: 'before',
            data: [ {value:'^$', label:'Empty' }], 
            filter_match_mode: 'regex',
            select_type: 'select2'
    }]);
```

2) Use [datatables HTML5 data-* attributes](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) ,

3) Use Chosen plugin (IMO Select2 fits datatables/yadcf better) instead of select2
 [see jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/m26jzxsf/12/)

```
        var oTable = $('#example').DataTable();

        yadcf.init(oTable, [
        {
            column_number: 0,
            filter_type: 'multi_select',
            append_data_to_table_data: 'before',
            data: [ {value:' ', label:'Empty' }], 
            filter_match_mode: 'exact',
            select_type: 'chosen'
        }]);
```

*always bet on yadcf*

Comment: Really thanks for your help again, Daniel. As other solutions, this works.

Comment: Hi again and thanks.

I have a new question about that. Will be possible to filter the empty fileds on filter_type: 'text' ???

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mgutbor/m26jzxsf/) and my explanation:

I want to have any possiblities to get the empty field on column PROJECT (Row with Status=ADD and RFC Status=Accepted).

Thanks again in advance.

Comment: you can try the `exclude` option, see this https://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/m26jzxsf/15/ filter for *PR* and check the *not* , if you will find a way to filter for empty string with datatables api let me know and I will try to add it to yadcf

Comment: Really thanks again for this one. I think with exclude option will be enough.

Comment: @Daniel How would you do the same for a regular yadcf Select2 (not multi)?